# Converting a vector in a cone statement to inequality constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

I would like to convert the following condition for $x$
\begin{align}
  x = N \lambda, \lambda \geq 0
\end{align}
to a pure linear inequality form, i.e. find an $L$ and eliminate $\lambda$
\begin{align}
  L x \leq 0
\end{align}
The first condition basically means "$x$ is in the cone generated by the columns of $N$", hence the set $x$ lives in should be a polytope with all faces containing the origin, justifying the form $Lx \leq 0$. But how exactly can I express $L$ in terms of $N$?

Comment: In my case, $N$ is full column rank. Can I do $N^\top x = N^\top N \lambda$, solve for $\lambda = (N^\top N)^{-1}N^\top x \geq 0$ ?

Comment: No, you can't. What that formula computes is the projection of $x$ over the range of $N$. For instance, if $N=[1, 0]^T$, then $x=[1,1]^T$ satisfies the inequality in your comment, but not the one in your question.

Comment: I see now. You are right.